# Lines between stacked columns in ng2-charts bar graph

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am working on `ng2-charts` stacked bar graph where I want to achieve separation between each series.  Something similar to below images. Line or Background shade anything is fine.

[image]

I have implemented stacked bar charts and line charts separately. How  can I achieve the lines/shades in stacked bar graph to differentiate the columns.

> [Stackblitz | Stacked bar graph](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-stacked-example-phxgt9)

> [Stackblitz | Line Chart](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-tpedzl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the line in the bar graph by passing the same data again with `type: line`to instead of `stack` in your example.

Replace below code

> ```
> public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
>   { data: [35, 41, 60, 19, 44, 45, 60, 46, 77, 64, 77, 56] , label: 'Series A', stack: 'a' },
>   { data: [65, 59, 40, 81, 56, 55, 40, 54, 23, 36, 23, 44], label: 'Series B', stack: 'a' }
> ];
> ```

with this

```
 public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
      { data: [35, 41, 60, 19, 44, 45, 60, 46, 77, 64, 77, 56] , label: 'Series A', stack: 'a' },
      { data: [35, 41, 60, 19, 44, 45, 60, 46, 77, 64, 77, 56] ,  type: 'line' }, // new line
      { data: [65, 59, 40, 81, 56, 55, 40, 54, 23, 36, 23, 44], label: 'Series B', stack: 'a' }
    ];
```

There may be better approach than this instead of duplicating the data. But I am not aware of any